# create auto increment registration number of student registration page

Tags: php, mysql, yii

i created a column name student id and set auto increment. but i want my registration number start from "ABC6788" . what i do ? please help me? my launguage is php mysql and yii framework.!

student_id        type-int   length-5     default-none        A I -Checked

and how replace this code for automatic registration number in create form page??

```
 <div class="row-left">
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($info,'student_id'); ?>
            <?php echo $form->textField($info,'student_id'); ?>
            <span class="status">&nbsp;</span>
        </div>
```

Comment: `auto-increment` is for `integer` types. Do you think `ABC6788` is a vaild integer?

Comment: no ..but i want set ABC6788 ?? how we do ??what change do ??

Comment: then you have to store in another field.

Answer (score 0):

you can't use `ABC6788` as an integer, so change to `varchar` maybe

and before save, get the last id, and set the primary accordingly,

**OR**

leave the primary key auto incremental as is and have another column with the value of your code

Comment: thanks dear sir ..but if we want start registration number "9876789"..then what we do ? what and where change ?please give brief . i am very new on php?

Comment: were you looking for this: `ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 9876789`

Comment: thanks sir...i change auto increment value , but i want it display on my user registration page ..besides text box ...my code is above..plz help me sir ???

Comment: was my answer helpful to you?

Answer (score 0):

Logic may be required behind auto-increment. get previous string. tokenize into ABC and 6788. increment second part by 1, and append it to first part. save it .

Answer (score 0):

In MYSQL it is not possible to have auto-increment for char values. there fore you can make the student_id as integer and do auto-increment. At the time of display you can echo the characters separately and then the student id.

```
 <div class="row-left">
        <?php echo "ABC" . $form->labelEx($info,'student_id'); ?>
        <?php echo "ABC" . $form->textField($info,'student_id'); ?>
        <span class="status">&nbsp;</span>
    </div>
```

hope this will help..

Comment: thanks sir ....but i want show always next registration number .on label on form ...how we show on label our next auto registration number on registration form ...besides textfield..on above code

Comment: its simple. in PHP there is a function called `lastInsertId()` using this function you can get the last inserted id in the table. with that number you can add +1. that's it. but first Google it and learn how to use `lastInsertId()` function in php.